# C# XNA: Custom drawing class isn't printing text though it has the location right

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

So I'm trying to draw some text with C# and XNA. I've got the `SpriteFont` loaded in fine, no bugs in the code and no compile-time warnings or errors. No errors get thrown during execution.

When I draw text from my main game class, it works fine. However, I've got a separate class which I'm trying to draw from. I've created an instance of it, called the constructor and the `Draw()` function of it, yet it still doesn't work.

Here's the main game class (the relevant bits anyway):

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Turquoise);

        if (!startScreen.hasRun)
        {
            // Works fine
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            spriteBatch.DrawString(spaceAge, "Score 0", new Vector2(50, 50), Color.Black);
            spriteBatch.End();

            // Fails to draw
            startScreen.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }
        else
        {
        }

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Here's the `Draw()` function of the `startScreen` instance that refers to (created from a separate `StartScreen` class in another file):

```
public Boolean Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        if (this.hasRun == false)
        {
            spriteBatch.Begin();

            spriteBatch.Draw(this.background, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.screenWidth, this.screenHeight), Color.White);
            spriteBatch.DrawString(this.font, "DevBuild: 001", new Vector2(this.textStart, 50), Color.Black);

            spriteBatch.End();

            /* Console.WriteLine("hasRun: " + hasRun);
            Console.WriteLine("screenWidth: " + Convert.ToString(screenWidth));
            Console.WriteLine("screenHeight: " + Convert.ToString(screenHeight));
            Console.WriteLine("dimensions.X: " + Convert.ToString(stringDimensions.X));
            Console.WriteLine("dimensions.Y: " + Convert.ToString(stringDimensions.Y));
            Console.WriteLine("textStart: " + Convert.ToString(textStart)); */
            // All the logs above give the right output

            this.hasRun = true;
            Console.WriteLine("hasRun: " + hasRun);
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
```

So why, when this function has the correct on-screen coordinates to draw the text at ( `(textStart, 50)` where `textStart` calculates to 312 on an 800-wide screen), and the call to `DrawString` is the same format, does the text not show up?

Feel free to ask for more code if it's necessary.

(N.B. The call to `spriteBatch.Draw` here doesn't work either, the image doesn't get drawn - perhaps this is the same issue?)

EDIT: I've tried the suggestion below: removed `Begin()` and `End()` from the StartScreen class and called `startScreen.Draw()` within the game's `Draw()` function in between a call to `Begin()` and `End()`. Still nothing gets drawn.

Comment: Try putting `startScreen.Draw(spriteBatch);` in between the `begin` and `end` calls in your main class, and remove the `begin` and `end` calls from the class.

Comment: Why are you need the hasRun variable? Does it set to false before each Draw() call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of making your draw method a public bool make it a public void and have a variable bool then it should work and your code should look like this:

```
bool drawn = false;
// defined at the top of your class so that the draw method doesn't need to be a bool

public Void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    if (this.hasRun == false)
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin();

        spriteBatch.Draw(this.background, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.screenWidth,this.screenHeight), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(this.font, "DevBuild: 001", new Vector2(this.textStart, 50), Color.Black);

        spriteBatch.End();

        /* Console.WriteLine("hasRun: " + hasRun);
        Console.WriteLine("screenWidth: " + Convert.ToString(screenWidth));
        Console.WriteLine("screenHeight: " + Convert.ToString(screenHeight));
        Console.WriteLine("dimensions.X: " + Convert.ToString(stringDimensions.X));
        Console.WriteLine("dimensions.Y: " + Convert.ToString(stringDimensions.Y));
        Console.WriteLine("textStart: " + Convert.ToString(textStart)); */
        // All the logs above give the right output

        this.hasRun = true;
        Console.WriteLine("hasRun: " + hasRun);
        drawn = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        drawn = false;
    }
}
```

also why does your Draw method need to have a bool at all from the code you have given it doesn't look like you used it anywhere

Comment: Seems viable. I'll give this a shot - the bool return is used in another class.